# How to decode email?

Tags: php, email, decode, encode

I am scraping one page and it has e-mails like `...&#109;&#97;&#105;&#108;&#116;&#111;&#58;&#83;&#116;&#101;&#119;&#97;&#114;&#116;&#46;&#83;&#109;&#105;&#1...` and similar. It is decoded, how could I encode it with PHP? Thanks (only for education purposes).

Comment: The string you show is still encoded.  You state that it is decoded, but it is not.  Also, HOW do you want to encode it in PHP?

Comment: @EricJ. I want to decode this text to normal address (like. name@mail.com)

Comment: i am not sure about but from the pattern of encoding i think it's encoded using ascii value of the characters with the prefix of &# and suffix of ;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are just ordinary ASCII characters which for mysterious reasons have been encoded in HTMLs numeric character format. i.e. the letter "a" is coded as `&#96;`.

A [list of common encodings](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm)

The built in php function [html-entity-decode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) should convert these back to readable utf-8.

Comment: It looks like they're doing this to obfuscate the email address and stop it from being found by automated scripts.

Answer (score 1):

try `html_entity_decode()` to get the encoded value.

for ex:

```
$str = "&#109;&#97;&#105;&#108;&#116;&#111";  
$string = html_entity_decode($str);
echo $string;
```

Answer (score 0):

Each entity is the decimal representation of a character. This Perl code will translate simple ASCII.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $mail = '&#109;&#97;&#105;&#108;&#116;&#111;&#58;&#83;&#116;&#101;&#119;&#97;&#114;&#116;&#46;&#83;&#109;&#105;&#1';

$mail =~ s/&#(\d+);/chr $1/eg;

print $mail;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
mailto:Stewart.Smi&#1
```